# wsgi - handle client timeouts

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm doing some basic wsgi stuff:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response("200", [])
    result = some_long_func()
    return [result]
```

It happens from time to time that the client disconnects before `some_long_func` completes and I see the following in my logs:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected)...
```

Is there a way to handle disconnected clients on the application level, i.e. before `application()` returns?

My server is uwsgi (standalone). No frameworks, just pure python.

Comment: No clue. But I'd sure like to know.

Comment: you should clarify what you mean for "handling" a disconnected client. if you want to just ignore it, you can do it with a uWSGI option, if you want to always be sure to execute code at the end of a request just use the WSGI close() method.

Comment: @roberto: I'd like to take some application-specific actions on disconnect, e.g. log an error into a DB, send a mail about that etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the iterable returned by the application has a close() method, the server or gateway must call that method upon completion of the current request, whether the request was completed normally, or terminated early due to an error.

So if `close()` is called before the output iterator has finished, you know client was disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

No. Within the bounds of the WSGI specification there is no way of handling this. Go search discussions on the mod_wsgi mailing list. One such discussion is:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/modwsgi/jr2ayp0xesk/QtINxMi_KUAJ

Comment: I'm confused. To quote your own reply there: "...when closure of connection is detected then a Python exception will be seen by the application and it is up to it as to what to do" - that's essentially what I'm looking for.

Comment: With the way your code is written you would not see it and be able to handle it, because you aren't using the write() callable (which you shouldn't be anyway) and are instead returning in an iterable of strings. Thus it is only going to be the WSGI server that sees the exception for the disconnection and thus why it typically just logs something. Given that using the write() callback is bad practice, the only time you would see an exception in your code is if your were block on read from wsgi.input when disconnection occurs.

Comment: I see. What I thought is to do `try: write("") except...` just before return just to ping the client and if it breaks, log the exception and return nothing, otherwise return the usual iterable. Is that a silly idea?

Comment: Well @thg435 didn't ask if it's possible with WSGI only. The server may have such mechanism. How about uwsgi.is_connected()? Name looks promising, unfortunately there is no doc for it.

Comment: The subject of the post was 'wsgi - handle client timeouts'. Looked like a WSGI question to me. Also, what was good about WSGI was that it allowed people to write portable web applications, the non standard WSGI extensions that some WSGI servers have been adding means we are returned to the bad old day of what are effectively proprietary interfaces and vendor lock in.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton While you are right, the reasoning is appropriate when you're building an API, not when you have to use an imperfect one. Anyway, you made me look through the specs, and actually there is a way.

Comment: Any way of trying to properly detect close of input when it occurs in WSGI will be an unreliable hack which is likely not going to be portable between WSGI server implementations. If this level of knowledge is important, you would be better off using an async web server such as async APIs of Tornado or Twisted.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Wanna do some stats? :) It does work with uwsgi.